# What relations View dependencies in SSMS don't show

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've heard that you cannot rely on SSMS view dependencies, that dependencies for objects on linked servers and dynamic code dependencies aren't showed. 
Is there anything else that is now recognized as dependency and shown? What dependencies are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done a 'proper' investigation into the behaviour, but I've certainly come to distrust the feature - I find that even local dependencies get out of date and I simply can't base critical decisions on the results (e.g. can I *really* delete that object)

Comment: Does this mean that the relations database diagrams can be wrong? If yes, is there a way to get a correct diagram?

Comment: Do you mean the foreign key relationships?  I fear I may have misunderstood your question...

Comment: Any relations. Can I be sure that database diagrams will be corect?

Comment: Yeah I don't see why not. My comment was on dependencies within sprocs etc